# How to set a variable as default value for a column ? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, request

I want to assign a value as default for a column.
It says that there is a syntax error at line 2 :

```
SELECT `id` into @idND FROM `xxx` WHERE `name`='John';
ALTER TABLE `xxx2` CHANGE `statut_id` `statut_id` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT @idND;
```

It works if I set DEFAULT 3 for example. What am I doing wrong please ?

Comment: You cannot assign a variable.Perhaps you are looking for generated columns.

Comment: I think generated column isn't the thing i'm looking for. Is there any way to put for example "3" as Default, using a variable (or something else) ? If not, what is the problem for not being implemented ?

Comment: @Jojoe you might be able to use a trigger to do this.  It depends on *why* you need the default value of `idND`.